# Navigation Menu Dropdown Error in IE only

Tags: internet-explorer, navigation

QUESTION:
In our navigation bar dropdown menu is no triggering the sub-navigation elements in one section of our website in IE only. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox. It seems as though the "parent open" action is not triggering in IE on the malfunctioning page. I'm not sure why. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Functioning page in IE
http://www.sosc.org/

Malfunctioning page in IE
http://www.sosc.org/intranet

Please note: entering my code in fiddle would not be useful to anyone in the future as there is a specific CMS in play in this issue and CMS specific code is inserted into our custom code. Also the code would be super convoluted. Please don't delete my question for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the js order in  the header and it works now